# Environment.TickCount does not match elapsed time from DateTime.Now

Tags: .net, windows, time

i have a nice loop that sleeps for about one minute and does the following code: (more or less pseudo, talking about C#, .NET Framework 4.0 Full Profile)

```
LocalSystemTimeStamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;
StartupTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
```

Also i have a check method that verifies the measured figures:

```
TimeSpan interval = current.LocalSystemTimeStamp - old.LocalSystemTimeStamp;
int projectedStartupTickCount = (int)(old.StartupTickCount+ interval.TotalMilliseconds);
if (Math.Abs(projectedStartupTickCount-current.StartupTickCount)>100)
{
   // log the mismatch
}
```

so, typically Environment.TickCount and the Clock should advance in a similar timescale and the difference between projectedStartupTickCount and the measured tickcount should match.

But, every now and then these do not match by some seconds (2 to 6 seconds in my case).
This is a lot the case at system startup, but occurs even while the system is up and running after some (random??) intervals. Somehow i think these do differ always when the system / cpu is under heavy load.

Can someone explain this behaviour? (or even point to the matching documentation?)

Comment: Why would you confuse ticks and milliseconds?

Comment: leppie is right: You add a tick value to a millisecond value (1 ms = 10,000 ticks). You should use `interval.Ticks`.

Comment: And I don't know how long your `interval` will be, but you shouldn't cast the tick count to `int`. A tick is a very short time span. `TimeSpan.FromTicks(int.MaxValue)` is only about 3 minutes and 35 seconds. You should use `long` instead.

Comment: I don´t think i mix them up: From the MSDN docs of Environment.TickCount: Gets the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started. It´s just a pity that it is called "tick". They have just nothing directly to do with the ticks from DateTime or TimeSpan

Comment: sorry, fero. You also miss the point. The cast is necessary because TotalMilliseconds is double.

Comment: Perhaps you're talking about when the network time service adjusts the clock to keep it in sync?

Comment: @HarryJohnston This sounds plausible - Anyone has a clue how i can determine if such an event occured? Just checking eventlog? Or some programmatic way?